# Can a graph with sharp edges be called monotonic?

Tags: calculus

[image]

the graph below satisfies the above condition but is it necessary that the function must also be smooth to be monotonic?

[image: this is the graph]`

Comment: smoothness is **not** a condition for monotonicity.

Comment: The cdf of a discrete distribution function is monotonic but not continuous, eg, binomial.